# How to decode mail content (imap)

Tags: php, codeigniter, imap

How to decode message body in php?

I use imap, sometimes it's work but not all message content.

//controller

[image: controller]

//code #view

[image: view]

//sample view 1

[image: view01]

//sample view 2

[image: view02]

//sample view 3

[image: view03]

Comment: Don't use screenshots but paste the code so others can try it out and help you with this problem.  Pasting code is done between 3 backticks. (See Markdown docs)

Comment: I have try to paste my code, but i get some error `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`